# How to view only one section in html

Tags: html

Can someone please help me with something. Im building a website and it includes html5. The thing that i dont understand is using the `<section>` function.

Preview

```
<section id="1">
    <a href="#2">click her to go to section 2</a>
</section>
```

this is the section 2

```
<section id="2">

<!-- html source where <p> and etc will go -->

</section> Closed Section
```

The section above is what i only want to be seen in the webpage instead of showing section 2. Its pretty much like having many pages in 1 just without reloading or scrolling down.

In my css i have scroll bar locked, and ive tried many things to make that section to only be show on the webpage. Im kindof learning new html5 functions and im experiencing the things now

http://jsfiddle.net/K2w49/

Comment: with Jquery could be easy `$('#2').hide();`

Comment: So add that in section 1? and inside section 2 add $('#1).hide();

Comment: Or use CSS to make the sections 100% height and width.

Comment: Note that, according to the html standards, an `id` must not begin with a digit. So `1` and `2` are **not** valid.

Comment: you can do it multiple ways, just google it, you can use, CSS, javascript, javascript and CSS, etc

Comment: So you want each section to take up 100% of your viewers screen?

Comment: This is an example! I will add the css and jquery things to it to see does that do any help

http://jsfiddle.net/K2w49/

Comment: Sorry but neither isnt working for me!
Check out http://jsfiddle.net/K2w49/
What is im doing wrong

Comment: @kcdwayne No i only want a section to be shown only. I dont want section 2 to be shown in section 1 until section 2 is activated to be shown, and after section 2 is shown section 1 will not be shown in section 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused about what a function is. `<section>` is an HTML5 *element*. No function involved.

If you're talking about having a seamless fullscreen interface (i.e. they never scroll, new stuff just loads in similar to Flash applications), then it doesn't really matter what html container you use (i.e. div, section, aside)

For example..

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <section id="slide-1" class="slide">
    <!-- content -->
  </section>
  <section id="slide-2" class="slide">
    <!-- content -->
  </section>
</div>
```

Then max the wrapper and attach an absolute or fixed value to it...

Here's what you asked for: http://jsfiddle.net/K2w49/7/

If you're going to have a lot of content, you should use AJAX to load as needed and change the script around a little.

Comment: no, all you're doing is copying my code (which was broken due to mismatched closing tags). To have what you're asking for and looking good on all sizes is pretty tricky technically... you may want to look around for a plugin or template that does what you want if it will have a lot of content.

Comment: @user3233575 check the fiddle I added.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my issue. I really appreciate you helping me @kcdwayne :)